# Can't click dynamic link using Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select dynamic links in a JavaScript table using Selenium.  Here is sample HTML code for one of the links I'm trying to click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: runCategoryReport(0,&quot;objectName=enrollee&amp;titleMessageKey=3-3-2&amp;time=month&amp;systemTypeMetaId=6&amp;categoryName=Attendee&quot;);">1925</a>
```

I've tried the following lines of code separately to click this specific link:

Option 1

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/*[contains(text(), '3-3-2')]").click()
```

Option 2

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, '3-3-2')]").click()
```

Both lines of code result in errors:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a/*[contains(text(), '3-3-2')]"} (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@onclick, '3-3-2')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

I'd appreciate any kind of feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue.  I added the `switch_to.frame` code and replaced the `find_element_by_xpath` path with the link's full xpath.

Here is the final code for anyone to reference:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/font/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a an [attribute CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors): `a[onclick*='3-3-2']`, which will find an `a` tag who has an attribute `onclick` that contains `'3-3-2'`.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='3-3-2']").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!  I tried it out and unfortunately received an error similar to what I mentioned above:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[onclick*='3-3-2']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: @RussellC Try waiting for the element to appear. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable) post.